# Multer req.body empty in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-file-upload, multer

I am using multer to upload form data( some image files).

But req.body and req.files both are coming empty. when I am uploading images I got the successful message " your image has been uploaded" but my folder is empty.

I tried all solution available on StackOverflow as well as GitHub. 
but no luck.

below my code

form in the HTML file

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="multerFile" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  <input type='text' id='random' name='random'>
  <br>
  <span id="status"></span>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadForm').submit(function () {
      $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
      $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function (xhr) {
          status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response)
          $("#status").empty().text(response);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

index.js

```
app.post('/multerFile', function (req, res) {
    console.log("hi i am multer function")
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: 'C:/Users/chandra/Documents/project/node_project/public'
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('userPhoto', 2);

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        } else {
            console.log(req.body)
            console.log(req.files);
            req.files.forEach(function (f) {
                console.log(f);
                // and move file to final destination...
            });
            res.end("File has been uploaded");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried:

[Express, Multer, BodyParser req.body empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354455/express-multer-bodyparser-req-body-empty-array)

[multer req.body showing empty always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801180/multer-req-body-showing-empty-always)

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/351

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/391

and I followed this tutorial for multer

https://codeforgeek.com/2016/01/multiple-file-upload-node-js/

I am unable to understand that what am I doing wrong?

please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try using one file, without uploding multiple files, if not try removing `multiple` flag from your file input and try again and see if error reoccurs

Comment: @JanithKasun I try with single file. now I am able to see details of file in req.files and it is showing successful message(file has been uploaded..) but I am not able to find file in destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my storage to

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: './public/uploads/',
       filename: function(req, file, cb){
         cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
       }
     });
```

And it is workings fine..

Comment: I just changed my storage

Comment: Ah the filename. Good.

Answer (score 0):

First, **.ajaxSubmit()** is not core jQuery functions. You need the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and I don't know if you import it like below:

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

The easiest way to do it will be to do it without a plugin like this:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function() {

  $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");

  var formData = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/multerFile',
      data: formData,
      success: function(response) {
          console.log(response)
          $("#status").empty().text(response);         
      },
      contentType: false, // Prevent jQuery to set the content type
      processData: false  // Prevent jQuery to process the data    
  });

  return false;

});
```

Now in your backend, your destination should better be (with a folder uploads in your public folder):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
});
```

Comment: thanks for giving me this solution but it is not working. when I am uploading no error occurred even file is coming in req.files but it is not stored in ./public/uploads/ or anywhere

Comment: same issue...not able to see uploaded file